# how to plot a random walk in 2d?

Tags: r, random

I'm trying to write a code of a reinforced random walk in which the next step depends on the previous choices:

```
 Next_step = function(i,j,Grille){
  
  l = nrow(Grille)
  prob = matrix(NA, nrow = l, ncol = l)
  
  if ((i==1)&&(1<j)&&(j<length(Grille))) {
    prob[i+1,j] = Grille[i+1,j]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i+1,j])
    prob[i,j+1] = Grille[i,j+1]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i+1,j])
    prob[i,j-1] = Grille[i,j-1]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i+1,j])
    Grille[i,j] = Grille[i,j]+1
    next_step = sample(c(2,3,4), 1,replace = TRUE, prob = c(prob[i,j-1],prob[i+1,j],prob[i,j+1]))
    
  } else if ((j==1)&&(1<i)&&(i<length(Grille))){  
    prob[i+1,j] = Grille[i+1,j]/(Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j]+Grille[i+1,j])
    prob[i,j+1] = Grille[i,j+1]/(Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j]+Grille[i+1,j])
    prob[i-1,j] = Grille[i-1,j]/(Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j]+Grille[i+1,j])
    Grille[i,j] = Grille[i,j]+1
    next_step = sample(c(1,3,4), 1,replace = TRUE, prob = c(prob[i-1,j],prob[i+1,j],prob[i,j+1]))
    
  } else if ((i==1)&&(j==1)){  
    prob[i+1,j] = Grille[i+1,j]/(Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i+1,j])
    prob[i,j+1] = Grille[i,j+1]/(Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i+1,j])
    Grille[i,j] = Grille[i,j]+1
    next_step = sample(c(3,4), 1,replace = TRUE, prob = c(prob[i+1,j],prob[i,j+1]))
    
  } else if ((i==length(Grille))&&(1<j)&&(j<length(Grille))){   
    prob[i,j+1] = Grille[i,j+1]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j])
    prob[i,j-1] = Grille[i,j-1]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j])
    prob[i-1,j] = Grille[i-1,j]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j])
    Grille[i,j] = Grille[i,j]+1
    next_step = sample(c(1,2,4), 1,replace = TRUE, prob = c(prob[i-1,j],prob[i,j-1],prob[i,j+1]))
    
  } else if ((j==length(Grille))&&(1<i)&&(i<length(Grille))) { 
    
    prob[i+1,j] = Grille[i+1,j]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i-1,j]+Grille[i+1,j])
    prob[i,j-1] = Grille[i,j-1]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i-1,j]+Grille[i+1,j])
    prob[i-1,j] = Grille[i-1,j]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i-1,j]+Grille[i+1,j])
    Grille[i,j] = Grille[i,j]+1
    next_step = sample(c(1,2,3), 1,replace = TRUE, prob = c(prob[i-1,j],prob[i,j-1],prob[i+1,j]))
    
  } else if ((i==length(Grille))&&(j==length(Grille))){  ## dernière case en bas à droite
    prob[i,j-1] = Grille[i,j-1]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i-1,j])
    prob[i-1,j] = Grille[i-1,j]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i-1,j])
    Grille[i,j] = Grille[i,j]+1
    next_step = sample(c(1,2), 1,replace = TRUE, prob = c(prob[i-1,j],prob[i,j-1]))
    
  } else if ((i==1)&&(j==length(Grille))) { 
    prob[i+1,j] = Grille[i+1,j]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i+1,j])
    prob[i,j-1] = Grille[i,j-1]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i+1,j])
    Grille[i,j] = Grille[i,j]+1
    next_step = sample(c(2,3), 1,replace = TRUE, prob = c(prob[i,j-1],prob[i+1,j]))
    
  } else if ((i==length(Grille))&&(j==1)) { 
    prob[i,j+1] = Grille[i,j+1]/(Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j])
    prob[i-1,j] = Grille[i-1,j]/(Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j])
    Grille[i,j] = Grille[i,j]+1
    next_step = sample(c(1,4), 1,replace = TRUE, prob = c(prob[i-1,j],prob[i,j+1]))
    
  } else { 
    prob[i+1,j] = Grille[i+1,j]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j]+Grille[i+1,j])
    prob[i,j+1] = Grille[i,j+1]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j]+Grille[i+1,j])
    prob[i,j-1] = Grille[i,j-1]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j]+Grille[i+1,j])
    prob[i-1,j] = Grille[i-1,j]/(Grille[i,j-1]+Grille[i,j+1]+Grille[i-1,j]+Grille[i+1,j])
    Grille[i,j] = Grille[i,j]+1
    next_step = sample(c(1,2,3,4), 1,replace = TRUE, prob = c(prob[i-1,j],prob[i,j-1],prob[i+1,j],prob[i,j+1]))
  }
  
  if (next_step == 1) { # up 
    i = i-1
  } else if (next_step ==2) { # left
    j = j-1
  } else if (next_step == 3) { # down 
    i = i+1
  } else if (next_step == 4) { # right 
    j = j+1
  }
  return(c(i,j))
}


RW_2d = function(nRow,nCol,pas){
  
  Grille = matrix(1, nrow = nRow, ncol = nCol)
  
  axe_x = rep(NA,nRow)
  axe_y = rep(NA,nCol)
  d = rep(NA,2)
  #sommets = rep(NA,pas) : : I put this here in order to return a matrix with which I can plot the occurrences of each point/vertex but it doesn't seem to work here 
  
  axe_x[1] = sample(1:nRow,1)
  axe_y[1] = sample(1:nCol,1)
  #sommets = d[1:2] 
  for (i in 2:pas){ 
    d[1:2]= Next_step(axe_x[i-1],axe_y[i-1],Grille)
    #sommets = cbind(sommets,d)
    axe_x[i]=d[1]
    axe_y[i]=d[2] 
  }
  plot(axe_x,axe_y,type = 'l')
  #sommets = matrix(sommets, nrow=2)
  #return(sommets)
}

RW_2d(5,5,6)
RW_2d(10,10,100) 
RW_2d(10,10,500)
RW_2d(10,10,1000)
RW_2d(100,100,1000)
```

When I try to run this code, I have an error message concerning the if statements and the indexes of Grille[i + 1, j]  and Grille[i, j+1] but I cannot find why I get this error.

Moreover, I'm also trying to plot, using my RW_2d function, a graph in which we can see the number of times each vertex has been chosen. I tried to return a "sommet" matrix of dimension 2*pas in order to do that but it sometimes didn't return a matrix on this dimension.

Does anyone have an idea of why I got this error message? and how to plot the number of occurrences of the vertices?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: it says Error in if ((i == 1) & (1 < j) & (j < length(Grille))) { :  argument is of length 0

Comment: You have `for (i in 1:pas-1)`. Have a look at `1:pas - 1`, I think you might need `1:(pas - 1)` instead.

Comment: thank you now I have the error "index out of bounds" for Grille[ i +1 , j ]

Comment: So what are you doing to make sure `i + 1` isn't bigger than the number of rows in `Grille`? It looks like the `i` argument is `axe_x[i]`, and `axe_x[1] = sample(1:nRow,1)`, so it's possible `axe_x[i]` is `nRow`, so indeed `nRow + 1` is out of bounds. I'm not sure what you want to do in this case so I can't fix your code, but the problem makes sense.